# NGEN.exe how to control?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ngen

how can I stop using **ngen.exe** on my windows 10. **I want to control all** the libraries that are generated. Every time I monitor the libraries a new library appears with the extension .ni.dll.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "control"?

Comment: Do you just want to disable it generally, or do you want to except specific dlls ?

Comment: The .Net framework analyzes the use of programs through metrics and makes the decision to compile some assembly's for machine language and in the NIC (native image cache) new .ni.dll appear overnight from one day to the next. I don't want these new .ni.dll to appear in my controlled environment.